# Are there any specialized reduce-like methods in the standard library?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Guido at one point mentioned the possibility of creating specialized `reduce` methods for the other associative operators beyond `sum`; was this ever done?

In his [blog post](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) discussing the intended removal of `reduce` (which was eventually cancelled), Guido reaffirms that `reduce` is generally bad practice except for with associative operators.  Then he suggests, instead of using `reduce` for associative operators, that a module could be created to house methods like `sum` for all of the associative operators.

> There aren't a whole lot of associative operators. (Those are operators `X` for which `(a X b) X c` equals `a X (b X c)`.) I think it's just about limited to `+`, `*`, `&`, `|`, `^`, and shortcut `and`/`or`. We already have `sum()`; I'd happily trade `reduce()` for `product()`, so that takes care of the two most common uses. The bitwise operators are rather specialized and we can put fast versions in a library module if there's demand.

I know there aren't any additions like `product` to the built-ins, but was such a library module added to the Python standard library?

Comment: No, there is nothing like `product`, but you can `import operator, functools` and use `functools.reduce(operator.mul, [2,4,6])`

Comment: Are you asking whether such generalizations exist in the standard library *right now*, whether they were ever part of the standard library, or whether anyone ever slapped something like this together and uploaded it to PyPI?

Comment: @jwodder updated my question. I'd like to know if this is in the standard library now, but I wouldn't mind hearing about a solution in PyPi.